# Show 'OPEN' button in IE, when html table Excel export using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, export-to-excel

I am using `<html xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">` to export Excel file. For differentiate browser I am using:

```
msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match  --> For IE 
else other browser
```

But when the file exports in IE the pop-up shows only save button and doesn't shows Open button. 
Can somebody please tell me how can I enable the Open button?

Comment: Ah, I see. No worries, then. We just received a moderator flag that there was a "rollback war" going on, and it looked to me like you were upset that someone was editing your question and trying to undo the changes. For future reference, if you go to the [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46073298/revisions) for your question (the link text is the "edited 20 hours ago"), then you can see a "rollback" link for each revision.

Comment: Great, and many thanks and to you and Brian for educating me (Brian if you can see this :) )